# pnpm workspace:* dependencies

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, pnpm

I have serious trouble installing an partial pnpm monorepo inside a Docker Conatiner.
The problem is that `docker build` fails at some `devDependencies`which should not even be installed.

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.12",
    "@types/ssh2-sftp-client": "7.0.0",
    "dotenv": "14.3.2",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "ts-node": "10.4.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.5",
    "@tts-tmc/eslint-config-typescript": "workspace:*",
    "@tts-tmc/ts-config": "workspace:*"
  }
```

in my `Dockerfile` I use fetch to get all dependencies

```
FROM node:14-alpine
ARG GITHUB_NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN

RUN npm i -g pnpm
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
# pnpm fetch does require only lockfile
COPY package.json bin/pnpm-lock.yaml /usr/app/
COPY bin/.npmrc /usr/app/.npmrc
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN pnpm install -r --offline --prod
```

but even tho ony `--prod` dependencies should be installed, docker can't build correctly due to the following error

`ERR_PNPM_NO_MATCHING_VERSION_INSIDE_WORKSPACE  In : No matching version found for @tts-tmc/eslint-config-typescript@* inside the workspace`

So is there a standard way how to solve this? or do I have to modify the package.json and if so, how would you get the correct versions? I thought tha the `lockfile? should be sufficient to install all dependencies.

Regards
Mathias

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I have a similar issue.

Comment: Hmm, not really, switched to `esbuild` and bundeld it differently

Comment: Got the same issue...

Comment: @MathiasMaerker Hi Mathias, could you help me understand how you switched to `esbuild` please? I'm having what seems to be exactly the same issue except with `eslint-config-custom` provided by Turborepo. Thank you.

Comment: @danielblythe Sure, but there is not much to explain. I just used `esbuild` to create a single file bundle with all needed dependencies inside and moved that file to a container instead of running the build inside the container. Thats about it

Comment: This thread might be useful: https://github.com/orgs/pnpm/discussions/4561. Run `pnpm -r update`

Answer (score 2):

Was getting the same error while shifting from `yarn` to `pnpm`! Resolved it by just adding `pnpm-workspace.yaml` with following contents:

```
packages:
  - "apps/*"
  - "packages/*"
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate a dedicated lockfile for your project. Install [@pnpm/make-dedicated-lockfile](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/tree/main/packages/make-dedicated-lockfile) and run `make-dedicated-lockfile` in `/usr/app`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, unfortunately it does not work, maybe that is related to this issue https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/3442

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if, as a Monorepo project, you have also distributed package. json in other places besides the package. json under root `COPY package.json bin/pnpm lock. yaml/usr/app/` can be optimized in general projects, but in Monorpo projects, it may be lost due to the loss of the workspace's package.json file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).