# Turborepo(Docker), PNPM workspace dependency package version mismatch

Tags: node.js, docker, pnpm, turborepo, pnpm-workspace

I am starting a project using Turborepo with PNPM as the package manager and for it to be Dockerised. I have installed Turborepo using `npx create-turbo@latest`(selecting PNPM during the setup) and have added a `docker-compose.yaml` file and `Dockerfile.local`'s for my `apps`, which as `docs`, `web` and `server`. apps/web Dockerfile.local can be found below as that appears to be where the error is coming from as you can see in the error logs it's runnning through the web dev/dependencies.

When I run my `make local` command(below) I get the following error in my terminal.

Terminal error

```
#0 0.732 @types/node is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/@types+node@17.0.45/node_modules/@types/node
#0 0.733 @types/react is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/@types+react@18.0.26/node_modules/@types/react
#0 0.733 @types/react-dom is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/@types+react-dom@18.0.10/node_modules/@types/react-dom
#0 0.733 eslint is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/eslint@7.32.0/node_modules/eslint
#0 0.733 typescript is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/typescript@4.9.4/node_modules/typescript
#0 0.734 next is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.0.0_pjwopsidmaokadturxaafygjp4/node_modules/next
#0 0.734 react is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react
#0 0.734 react-dom is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom
#0 0.734 react-query is linked to /app/node_modules from /node_modules/.pnpm/react-query@3.39.2_biqbaboplfbrettd7655fr4n2y/node_modules/react-query
#0 0.741  ERR_PNPM_NO_MATCHING_VERSION_INSIDE_WORKSPACE  In : No matching version found for eslint-config-custom@* inside the workspace
#0 0.741 
#0 0.741 This error happened while installing a direct dependency of /app
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pnpm install]: exit code: 1
make: *** [local] Error 17
```

apps/web package.json

```
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --port 3002",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "ui": "workspace:*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.7",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
    "tsconfig": "workspace:*",
    "typescript": "^4.5.3"
  }
}
```

Makefile

```
local:
    @docker-compose stop && docker-compose up --build --remove-orphans;
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./apps/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "${FRONTEND_PORT}:${FRONTEND_PORT}"
    networks:
      - gh-network
    command: "npm start"
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./apps/server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./apps/server:/svr/app
      - "./scripts/wait.sh:/wait.sh"
      - /svr/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - gh-network
    ports:
      - "${BACKEND_PORT}:${BACKEND_PORT}"
    depends_on:
      - gh-pg-db
    links:
      - gh-pg-db
  gh-pg-db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: gh-pg-db
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - gh-network
  pgadmin-portal:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    container_name: pgadmin-portal
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT}:80"
    depends_on:
      - gh-pg-db
    networks:
      - gh-network
volumes:
  pgdata:
  pgadmin:

networks:
  gh-network:
    driver: bridge
```

apps/web Dockerfile.local

```
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN npm i -g pnpm
RUN pnpm --version
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pnpm install
```

I have tried checking the versions of eslint-config-custom in the web `package.json` and it's `7.32.0` whereas the eslint version in the shared package is `7.23.0`. I have amended these to match but it did not work.

My expected outcome is for the `make local` command to successfully boot up the project so I can see the initial Next/React files from Turborepo in my browser at port 3002.

I have looked at the following question([pnpm workspace:* dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378111/pnpm-workspace-dependencies)) but unfortunately to solve the problem the question asker switched their build tools which I cannot do as I'm using Turborepo.